# ARIMA function does not output AICC, BIC, x, or fitted values. Am I not formatting the time series correctly?

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I am trying to plot the observed versus fitted values for a time series data set however my output from the ARIMA function looks to be missing some attributes compared to the example I am following, so I am curious as to if I set up my model incorrectly.

I am following the example below which is from a data set in the forecast library.

```
fit <- Arima(WWWusage,order=c(3,1,0))
plot(fit$x,col="red")
lines(fitted(fit),col="blue")
```

The output here displays a nice visual representation of the data.

I am using a data set that can be found here: https://datamarket.com/data/set/22xa/lenex-corporation-shipment-of-can-openers-jan67-dec71#!ds=22xa&display=line

I uploaded the data then tried to turn it into a time series data set using the following:

```
   ship.ts <- ts(ship.ts, frequency=12, start = c(1967,1))

   stationary.ship <- diff(ship.ts, differences= 1)

   fit2 <-arima(stationary.ship, order = c(3,0,4))

   plot(fit2$x,col="red")
   lines(fitted(fit2),col="blue")
```

The code above throws and error saying there is no x value and when I look at the structure of both data sets I notice fit is a list of 18 while fit2 is only a list of 14. The missing attributes look to be AICC, BIC, x, and fitted. Is there a reason why I am getting these attributes?

Comment: Voting to close because you just have a typo: it should be `Arima` rather than `arima` when defining `fit2`.

Comment: @JuliusVainora wow, I feel like such a nincompoop.. after fixing the typo i got the correct number of attributes. My apologies for such a mediocre question! Thank you for your response though I appreciate it!!